# Tableview row stays selected after coming back from push segue

Tags: iphone, segue

My view controller is an `UIViewController`. I've added `UITableView` to the `UIView`. When the tableview row is selected, a push segue fires a new view controller. However, when coming back from the new view controller, the selected row stays selected. I didn't have this problem when my first controller was an `UITableviewController`, but I had to change it to an `UIViewController`, because I wanted to add activity indicator to my view.
The other thing I noticed is that when my first controller was a `UITableviewController`, `viewDidLoad` wasn't called when coming back from the new view controller (but now it's called).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add...

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: what if the user want blueSelection on row select

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` so I added `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` to `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method instead. But what's the reason of this behaviour when compared to my initial solution where my first controller was an UITableViewController?

Comment: May be in that case you had set No Selection in InterfaceBuilder

Comment: @Rajneesh071 using this method, blue selection is shown like a blink. As it first gets selected for a while and then deselected!

Comment: but bro for this you have to maintain indexPath.. you have to create global NSIndexPath ... and for better application use as possible as less global variable...

Comment: I get indexPath like this: `NSIndexPath*indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Comment: @Atif No, that wasn't the issue. I had set the gray style.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 No... you don't need to even get `indexPath`. If you look at header of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, it looks as '-(void)tableView:(UITableView)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath'... So you don't need to take a global variable.

Comment: @Shiim: you did an extra step, just use the indexPath that you get in functions parameter :)

Comment: @Atif That would be if I'd use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but since I've chosen not to use that method, I have to do `NSIndexPath*indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`. I have to take this variable anyway, because there is some other stuff I'm doing with it.

Comment: @Atif - according to his question "stays selected after coming back"   so when you are coming back to view then when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called..???

Comment: No, it calls when cell is selected... On return, he doesn't need to show selection. Just when tapped, it blinks with blue color and moves to next view. When comes back, cell doesn't highlight with blue color as per his requirement

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

This will help you out...

Comment: what if the user want blueSelection on row select?

Comment: Thanks, this solution works also (when added to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), but I've selected Atif's answer, because he was the first one to answer.

Answer (score 4):

This mechanism, a variation of the suggested answers, removes the selection when the detail view disappears, but also helps the user know what they selected to get to the detail view:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:YES];
}
```

This appears to be what Apple is doing in their own apps. See the behavior when a Contact record is selected in the Contacts app for an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can Add

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`  delegate.

Or you can do

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - and this solution works also. If I could select more answers as the solution...

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0:

`tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`

Answer (score -1):

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

This might help as an updated answer to the question.

Found some information on this topic here. http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2